# How to handle Ctrl + Break or Ctrl + Pause in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

My requirement is when ever user pressed Ctrl+Pause in my windows application I want to show some message to user. How to capture Ctrl+Pause in the windows form using Keydown event.

Comment: Those are keys that are used for console mode apps.  A user will never think to press them in a gui app.  Don't add undiscoverable features to a program, it is a waste of energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+Pause generate special KeyCode: Cancel

```
void myForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Cancel) //Control + Pause
  {
    //Code for showing message goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for WinForms. If anyone is after the equivalent for WPF, the key binding is `<KeyBinding Key="Cancel" Modifiers="Control"/>`. You need to include the `Control` modifier.

Answer (score 3):

The event handler would look something like this:

```
void myForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Pause && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
    {
      //Code for showing message goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1921323 How are we to know what you have tried when you did not show us any effort? And, "it's not working" is not a helpful description of a technical problem.

Comment: Can you please try and give me the reply.